# WPF - add static items to a combo box

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I've said it before and I'll say it again, the easiest examples for WPF are also the hardest to find on the web :)

I have a combo box that I need to display but it doesn't need to be databound or anything else, the content is static. How can I add a static list of items to my combo box using XAML?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Here is the code from MSDN and the link - [Article Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753382(VS.85).aspx), which you should check out for more detail.

```
<ComboBox Text="Is not open">
    <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi1">Item1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi2">Item2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi3">Item3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 22):

Like this:

```
<ComboBox Text="MyCombo">
<ComboBoxItem  Name="cbi1">Item1</ComboBoxItem>
<ComboBoxItem  Name="cbi2">Item2</ComboBoxItem>
<ComboBoxItem  Name="cbi3">Item3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also add items in code:

```
cboWhatever.Items.Add("SomeItem");
```

Also, to add something where you control display/value, (almost categorically needed in my experience) you can do so. I found a good stackoverflow reference here:

[Key Value Pair Combobox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521152/key-value-pair-combobox-in-wpf)

Sum-up code would be something like this:

```
ComboBox cboSomething = new ComboBox();
cboSomething.DisplayMemberPath = "Key";
cboSomething.SelectedValuePath = "Value";
cboSomething.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Something", "WhyNot"));
cboSomething.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Deus", "Why"));
cboSomething.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Flirptidee", "Stuff"));
cboSomething.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Fernum", "Blictor"));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<ComboBox Text="Something">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Item1"></ComboBoxItem >
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Item2"></ComboBoxItem >
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Item3"></ComboBoxItem >
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Please add information as too why your solution might help the OP

Comment: I find it helpful to know that the "Content" property is what's displayed on the form, which the other answers -- including mine -- did not illustrate.