# Combobox with static and dynamic data

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox

I would like to create a combobox that binds to a dynamic resource and has a custom xaml pre-specified list that stays at the top. I know how to bind a combobox to a dynamic resource,

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBox1" Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

and I know how to insert static items (see [WPF - add static items to a combo box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791784/wpf-add-static-items-to-a-combo-box) ).

```
<ComboBox Text="Is not open"> 
  <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi1">Item1</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi2">Item2</ComboBoxItem>     
  <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi3">Item3</ComboBoxItem> 
</ComboBox>
```

but I don't know how to do both at the same time?

Note: obviously, there are plenty of different ways to do this with custom widgets and the like, I just feel this should be quite easy somehow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[CompositeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx) is pretty cool for this.  Something like so:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={...whatever...}" />
            <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi1">Item1</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi2">Item2</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi3">Item3</ComboBoxItem>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: **Helpful hint** You can add a `<Separator/>` tag between `<ComboBoxItem>` or `<ListBoxItem>` 's to separate the static from dynamic content