# Combobox with static and dynamic data together in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

As the title suggests I want to add a static Item to a dataBound ComboBox.

I have refered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712500/combobox-with-static-and-dynamic-data) post.

Databinding a Combobox :

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBox1" Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

Adding Static Items to a combobox :

```
<ComboBox Text="Is not open"> 
  <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi1">Item1</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi2">Item2</ComboBoxItem>     
  <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi3">Item3</ComboBoxItem> 
</ComboBox>
```

Doing the above things together using CompositeCollection :

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.Items>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={...whatever...}" />
            <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi1">Item1</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi2">Item2</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi3">Item3</ComboBoxItem>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.Items>
</ComboBox>
```

But the above examples does not solve my problem.

I want to add a static Item to a dataBound ComboBox **in which I use DataTemplate**

Here is my Code for dataBound ComboBox (I don't know how to add static Items):

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbUnder" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects}"
            IsEditable="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroup, Mode=TwoWay}"
            TextSearch.TextPath="GroupName" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="3">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}" Width="250"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CorrespondingEffect}" />
                    </VirtualizingStackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

**Update as requested by aks81 :**

Here is the code for GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects

```
public GroupsViewModel()
{
    using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities())
    {
        GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects = (from g in db.Groups
                                         select new GroupAndCorrespondingEffect
                                                    {
                                                        GroupName = g.Name,
                                                        CorrespondingEffect = g.Type_Effect.Name
                                                    }
                                        ).ToList().OrderBy(g => g.GroupName);

        Items = (from e in db.Type_Effect
                 select e.Name).ToList();
    }
}

public static GroupsViewModel CurrentInstance { get { return Instance; } }

private IEnumerable<GroupAndCorrespondingEffect> _groupsAndCorrespondingEffects;
public IEnumerable<GroupAndCorrespondingEffect> GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects
{
    get
    {
        return _groupsAndCorrespondingEffects;
    }
    set
    {
        _groupsAndCorrespondingEffects = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects");
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I'm a bit confused. What do you mean by static items? The problem is not, that I don't understand your intention, but since you have already assigned an `ItemsSource`. It's not clear, why and what you want to add additionally.

Comment: Yes, I already have assigned an ItemsSource. This ItemsSource will get the data from Database. But I want to add an item before the data from Database is populated.

Comment: Instead of adding the `ComboBoxItem` using `xaml` why don't you add it in the Collection `GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects` itself? Also please move the `VirtualizingStackPanel` from `ItemTemplate` to `ItemsPanel`. Use a grid in `DataTemplate`

Comment: @aks81 can you show me an example of what you want to explain?

Comment: @aks81 The answer to your question in the above comment is that I want to add two items 1. the item that should not be selectable and should behave as header 2. the item with regular behavior. regular item can be added programatically but I don't find any method like add() on GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects.

Comment: Any possibility for you to share the code for Property `GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects`

Comment: Yes, I have access to whole project. And I have updated the question as per your request

Comment: Okay so its an `IEnumerable`. At which step do you want to add some values to the `GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects`? What you can do is cast `GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects` to a `List<GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects>` then add your static values and then cast back to an `IEnumerable`. I assume that you will need to add these static values only once and not often.

Comment: It was a preety easy solution. But I want to know how to add it directly to comboBox Items using XAML. Because I want to use it as a header. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link and let me know if it was useful :)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/86229c53-15bd-4780-bee3-c6c2cdae81e7/select-multiple-checkboxes-placed-inside-a-combobox

have a nice day!