# How to display a bound combobox with additional hardcoded items?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

We often use comboboxes to use to filter the data on a form.

Example: a combobox with the items: 'Any Film Genre', 'Comedy', 'Action', 'Romance'.

'Any Film Genre' is a hardcoded item that is used to show all films, whereas the latter three are generated from a data source.

Moving to WPF, I don't think this is the best method as I cannot bind a combobox's itemsource then add an item to a combobox.

So I think that I should either add an intermediate data layer or change how this is displayed?

Which should I do (or is there a better way)?

James

Comment: Why not add your hardcoded items to the `ItemsSource` list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [CompositeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx) as demonstrated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712500/combobox-with-static-and-dynamic-data)