# WPF combox with static values

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I need to assign few static combo box for my WPF application. I am doing as below.
I am getting error the content is not recognisable? How best I can assign them statically where I get the selectedIndex and value and also set them accordingly?

```
<ComboBox Name="month" >
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="January" content="01" />
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="February" content="02" />
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF - add static items to a combo box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791784/wpf-add-static-items-to-a-combo-box)

Comment: That is because of case sensitivity, Content, not content.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ComboBox` has `ComboBoxItem` in its body. So the selected value must be first type-casted as ComboBoxItem. And then when it is casted, you can get the value by .value attribute. See the code below.

In XAML

```
<ComboBox x:Name="month">
   <ComboBoxItem Content="January"/>
   <ComboBoxItem Content="February"/>
   ...
</ComboBox>
```

In C#

```
ComboBoxItem selectedItem = (ComboBoxItem)month.SelectedValue;
int index = month.SelectedIndex; //To get selected Index
int monthNumber = index + 1;
string itemvalue = selectedItem.Content;
```

You don't need the `Tag` attribute.

Comment: How can I do same for the year combo box? Its also possible to pre select it based on the current month and year.?

Comment: May I know, how many years do you want in that combo box. Because if there are many years, I suggest you go for databinding

Comment: Yes I may need many years say 10. So what is the best mechanism

Answer (score 0):

To add infinite year as the user scroll down
Using this code, whenever last year of combobox comes into view, next 10 years will be added to combobox and shown to user. I hope this is what you wanted.
`RequestBringIntoView` event is fired whenever a XAML component comes into view i.e when it is visible to user

```
   public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PopulateNextTenYears();
    }



    private void PopulateNextTenYears()
    {
        //Check to see whether the year_combo is empty.
        //If yes, then simply add years from today to next 10 years
        if(year_combo.Items.Count==0)
        {
          for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
          {
              ComboBoxItem itemCombo = new ComboBoxItem()
              {
                  Content=""+(DateTime.Now.Year+i)
              };

              if(i==9)
              {
                  //If the combobox item is last, then register it to RequestBringIntoView event handler
                  itemCombo.RequestBringIntoView += itemCombo_RequestBringIntoView;
              }
              //Add the combobox item to year_combo
              year_combo.Items.Add(itemCombo);
          }
        }
            //If year_combo has some items i.e it is not empty, then extract the last year from combobox
            //using this year, add 10 more years
        else
        {
            ComboBoxItem itemCombo = (ComboBoxItem)year_combo.Items[year_combo.Items.Count - 1];
            int nextYear = Convert.ToInt32(itemCombo.Content)+1;
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                 itemCombo = new ComboBoxItem()
                {
                    Content = "" + (nextYear + i)
                };

                if (i == 9)
                {
                    //Again if the last item is added, then register it to RequestBringIntoView event
                    itemCombo.RequestBringIntoView += itemCombo_RequestBringIntoView;
                }
                year_combo.Items.Add(itemCombo);
            }
        }
    }

    void itemCombo_RequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
    {
        //Omce an event has been raised by a particular last combobox item, it is important to
        //unregister its RequestBringIntoView event
        ComboBoxItem itemCombo = (ComboBoxItem)sender;
        itemCombo.RequestBringIntoView -= itemCombo_RequestBringIntoView;
        //Populate next 10 years
        PopulateNextTenYears();
    }
```

Comment: hi I dont quite get this function itemCombo_RequestBringIntoView?

Comment: RequestBringIntoView is fired whenever a XAML element like textbox, textblock, combobox element etc comes to the view of user i.e it is visible to user....just type RequestBringIntoView in combobox XAML and automatically this event will be created in backend...just like how you write Click events